# Sample size from a confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider a large lot of electronic components where there is interest
>   in the proportion of T working components. Suppose it is know for sure
>   that $$0.7 < T < 0.9$$ How many components ought to be randomly
>   sampled to provide an 80% confidence interval with length less than
>   0.01?

How do you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a standard deviation $\sqrt{T(1-T)}$ for a sample of size $1$.  If $0<T<1$ then $\sqrt{T(1-T)}\le1/2$.  But if it is known that $0.7<T$, then the standard deviation is $\le\sqrt{(0.7)(1-0.7)}\cong0.46$.  The standard error for a confidence interval based on a sample of size $n$ is therefore $\le0.46/\sqrt{n}$.  The length of the interval is about $2\cdot1.28\cdot0.46/\sqrt{n}$.  (The number $1.28$ is something you get from a table).  So you want to make $n$ big enough so that that is $\le0.01$.

Comment: The first part of the solution says, "First, we find that 0.07 < T(1-T) < 0.27 and Z* = 1.28. How did that interval pop up? I'm not sure if I am understanding this stuff

Comment: If $T=0.7$ then $T(1-T)=0.21$ (not $0.27$) and if $T=0.9$ then $T(1-T)=0.09$ (not $0.07$).  Maybe $0.07$ and $0.27$ are typos?

Comment: The answer for it is n>4587.32 which is different from yours. For yours I got around somewhere n > 13000 is this correct?

Comment: You need $2\cdot1.28\cdot0.46/\sqrt{n}\le0.01$, so $n\ge\left(\dfrac{2\cdot1.28\cdot0.46}{0.01}\right)^2$.  So $n\ge 13868$.  But I wouldn't be sure about that last digit since $1.28$ is rounded and the last one or two digits are sensitive to rounding.

Comment: Just curious, Why was the limit set to <= 1/2 near the beginning of your pos

Comment: @user2472706 : Complete the square: $T(1-T)=T-T^2$ ${}=-T^2+T$ ${}=-(T^2-T)$ ${}=-(T^2-T+\frac14)+\frac14$ ${}= \frac14-(T-\frac12)^2)$.  So this is equal to $1/4$ when $T=1/2$ and $<1/4$ when $T=\text{anything else}$.  Then take square roots.